# Java montecarlo simulation for poker

Tags: java, probability, montecarlo

I am a beginner in java and I have been working on a java program that gives probability of getting exactly one pair on a hand of 5 in poker by monte carlo simulation. I wrote the code but i am getting a probability of 58 percent while the actual probability is 42 percent. Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code. Here is my code.... Also if there are better ways to do it please tell me.

```
public class StdStats
{
    public static double a_pair(String[] a, double trials)
    {
        double times = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
        {
            //shuffling the card
            for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
            {
                int r = k + (int) (Math.random() * (a.length-k));
                String temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[r];
                a[r] = temp;
            }

            //initializing the needed variables
            boolean found = false;
            String[] cards = new String[5];
            int length = 5;

            //giving five cards randomly from the shuffled deck of card
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                int card = (int) (Math.random() * a.length);
                cards[j] = a[card];
            }

            //searching for the one pair
            for (int l = 0; l < length; l++)
            {
                char[] cardm = cards[l].toCharArray();
                //we have the first that is cardm and we look for the rest of the array to see if there 
                is another one(same)
                for (int m = l + 1; m < length; m++)
                {
                    char[] cardms = cards[m].toCharArray();
                    if (cardm[0] == cardms[0])
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found == true)
                {
                    times += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return times / trials;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] RANKS = {
                "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
        };

        String[] SUITS = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
        String[] deck = new String[RANKS.length * SUITS.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < RANKS.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SUITS.length; j++) {
                deck[SUITS.length * i + j] = RANKS[i] + " of " + SUITS[j];

            }
        }
        System.out.println(a_pair(deck, 100000));

    }
}
```

Comment: In your program you are looking if there are 2 cards that are the same and you count that as a hit. But it will also count 3 or 4 of the same cards as a hit. Therefore, it counts too many combinations. You'll have to check for **exactly** two of the same card instead of **at least** two of the same card.

Comment: Also, when you draw cards from the deck, there is the possibility that you draw exactly the same card twice (you don't remove a card from the deck when it is drawn). Note: When the deck is shuffled you can just take the top 5 cards, there's no need to randomly select cards from the shuffled deck.

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't get what you mean by counting 3 or 4 of the same cards as a hit...i am breaking the loop as soon as i found the first pair so would you mind explaining?Thanks for the advise of removing the card once used and taking cards from the shuffled deck.

Comment: Yes, you are breaking the loop as soon as you found the first pair. But it's possible that in that case there are actually 3 or 4 of the same rank on the hand. Instead of stopping at finding the second card of the same rank, you should also check if there are not more than 2. Otherwise you count 3 of a kind and 4 of a kind as if it is a pair also.

Comment: Thank you so much today i completed all the possible situations of this poker game.